# If two persons A & B have two large boolean lists, how to find the first mismatch in the lists with least transfer of data between the two persons?

Tags: hash, comparison, data-transfer

Let's say the list with person A = [T, T, F, T, F ...] and list with person B = [T, T, F, T, T ...], then we need to say that index 4 is the first mismatch position in the lists.
The number of entries in the lists can be very large (~50 million). How do we perform this search efficiently with the least amount of data (bytes) transferred between the two persons?

Comment: You can use Merkle tree, and adapt it for you task.

Comment: Thank you. I learnt that Merkle trees are used for hashing any data and creating a tree of data hashes out of it. Is there any optimisation that can be done from the fact that the list contains only boolean values?

Comment: Usually Merkle tree leaf contain hash of item in array. Since you have boolean values you leaf can hash 32 values in once (for example: 0-31, 32-63, and so on for 256 bit hash function).

Comment: Got it, can you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Merkle tree structure and find mismatch in `O(log n)` transfers. For 256 bit hash function (for example SHA256), you can split array by parts of 256 elements. This parts will be leafs of Merkle tree.